# Navigate to UIViewController from a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

My app header is currently a full width, 65pt height UIView which I then use as a generic header for all pages.

```
class AppHeader: UIView {
    ...
}
```

Then, in my *Main.storyboard* I have a UIViewController with a View from the object library which has its class specified as *AppHeader*.

My AppHeader (UIView) has multiple buttons which should, if clicked, take you to from the page/controller you're currently on to another.

From the AppHeader class I do not have access to use the present method to show another controller as its not within scope.

Here is my AppHeader.xib:

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is very bad behaviour, you should not use a UIView as a header. You should add a Navigation View Controller as the first view controller of your app. Navigation view controller has the navigation bar where you can put the buttons you want there. From that ones, you will be able to push or present other view controllers.

Check the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html

Comment: Oh, I just looked at the picture. He is duplicating the behavior of a navigation bar, isn't he?

Answer (score 1):

Make your `AppHeader` view a custom subclass of `UIView` if it isn't already. Wire the actions on the button to `IBAction` methods in the view.

Create a protocol `AppHeaderDelegateProtocol`. Give your `AppHeader` class a weak delegate property. Define methods in that protocol that let the `AppHeader` notify it's owning view controller about button presses.

Implement your `AppHeaderDelegateProtocol` in view controllers that will contain instances of `AppHeader`.

Connect the delegate property to each instance of `AppHeader`'s owning view controller.

That should do it.

Comment: My answer provides a way to do what you ask, but as Joan says in his answer, the better answer is "Don't do that."

Answer (score 0):

You can create a protocol - call it AppHeaderDelegate or something - and set up your other viewControllers to adopt that protocol.  You could define functions to let your delegate know that a certain button was pressed, and your delegate viewController can react to that by presenting the correct view controller.

Apple's docs on protocols [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html).

Alternatively, you can use NotificationCenter to broadcast notifications to let subscribers know that a certain button was pressed, and have your viewControllers listening for these notifications and reacting to them accordingly.  You have to manage when classes start/stop listening, though, as you may have several objects trying to react to a single notification.